# Inverse function of $g(x) = x/\sqrt{\log(1/x)}$.

Tags: functions, inverse

Is there a known inverse function for

> $$ g(x) = x/\sqrt{\log(1/x)}, \quad x \in (0,1) $$

at least for part of its domain? At a first glance this looks suspiciously like the definition of the Lambert W function but this does not seem so simple. From numerical evidence, I can tell that the inverse behaves essentially like the identity function for small values of $y$ in $g(x) = y$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found $$
x = \exp \left( { - \frac{1}{2}W\!\left( {\frac{2}{{g^2 (x)}}} \right)} \right).
$$ starting with the observation that $$
\frac{2}{{g^2 (e^{ - t} )}} = 2te^{2t} .
$$

Comment: @Gary Perhaps you would like to post a full answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that for any $t>0$,
$$
\frac{2}{{g^2 (e^{ - t} )}} = 2te^{2t} ,
$$
thus
$$
2t = W\!\left( {\frac{2}{{g^2 (e^{ - t} )}}} \right),
$$
i.e.,
$$
x = \exp \left( { - \frac{1}{2}W\!\left( {\frac{2}{{g^2 (x)}}} \right)} \right)
$$
for any $0<x<1$. Thus the inverse function of $g(x)$ is
$$
g^{ - 1} (x) = \exp \left( { - \frac{1}{2}W\!\left( {\frac{2}{{x^2 }}} \right)} \right),
$$
defined for all $x>0$. Here I denote by $W$ the principal branch of the Lambert $W$-function.